# Setting up a Table View Controller in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I'm trying to create a table as the main screen of my app and I'm having some issues. I set up the main.storyboard correctly, but there's an override func I have that "doesn't override a superclass". The error is on the nuberOfRowsInSection override func line. Here's my code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    var candies = [Candy]()

    @IBOutlet weak var editButton: UIButton!

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            // Do any additional setup
            // after loading the view.

            self.candies = [Candy(name: "Jolly Rancher"),Candy(name: "Snickers"),Candy(name: "Twix"),Candy(name: "Butterfinger"),Candy(name: "Milky Way")]
        }
     override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, nuberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.candies.count
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell

        var candy : Candy

        candy = candies [indexPath.row]

        cell.textLabel?.text = candy.name
    }


    @IBAction func editButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        editButton.setTitle("Save", forState: UIControlState.Normal)
    }

}
```

Comment: I caught the spelling error, but after i fixed that the error moved to the closing curly bracket after cell.textLabel?.text = candy.name

Comment: missing return in a function expected to return UITableViewCell

Comment: You have to return the cell. I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typing mistake. You call the method `nuberOfRowsInSection`. There is a 'n' missing. The method should be called `numberOfRowsInSection`.

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.candies.count
}
```

Also you have en error in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method. You have to return the cell:

```
return cell
```

Comment: oops thank you. but when i do that the error moves to the closing curly bracket after cell.textLabel?.text = candy.name

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess:

```
  //  this should read "numberOfRowsInSection": ~~v   
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, nuberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.candies.count
}
```

As far as I know, `UITableViewController` does not have a method with a parameter `nuberOfRowsInSection`, but it does have one with a parameter `numberOfRowsInSection`.

When dealing with something that isn't working, please start by checking your code for spelling mistakes.